# How can I CHANGE shared preferences values from another activity?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I got a few activities and one called `SettingsActivity`. I've created shared preferences there (just one Boolean value for now, but it'll be more).

I want to store values in there and access (not only access but actually change) the values of it in all of my other activities. How can I change this Boolean value from other activity?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Shared preferences should be equally accessible from any activity AFAIK.  I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Your question is already implemented in android. Just do it.

Comment: How can you CHANGE shared preferences values from another activity? Answer: the same way you would CHANGE it from original activity. Welvome. By purpose: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have created a `SharedPreference`, its already available in all other activities for being accessed from them.

I hope while you are saving this, you are doing something like the following.

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("SOME_KEY", booleanValue).apply();
```

Now when you are getting it from another activity you need to do something like the following.

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.getBoolean("SOME_KEY", defValue);
```

`SharedPreference` stores key-value pair and hence you can find the value against the key wherever you want to get it.

Now you can change it from any activity. Just use the same key for referencing it from other activities.

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_APP_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("SOME_KEY", otherBooleanValue).apply();
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. I don't know what I did wrong, i tried mostly the same, but I edited differently (I created an Editor object) . Anyway I've deleted that code already)) sorry for that noobie question